# Unable to Authenticate login page in Django when created a new database using Models.py

Tags: python, django

I have created a new table using models.py and this table stores data to my models.py table which I created. 
Now when I am going to my login page its not able to authenticate the details from that table and always gives invalid credentials.

My app name which I created is User and the table name which is stored in SQLite is User_register

Login.html

```
<div class="wrapper gradient">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row centered-form">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><center><b>Login To Web App!!</b></center> </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                                {% for message in messages %}
                            <p style="color:black;">{{message}}</p>
                            {%  endfor %}
                            </div>


                            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Models.py

```
class Register(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=90)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=90)
```

Views.py

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return render(request,'index.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid credentials')
            return render(request,'login.html')
    else:

        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: By default `auth.authenticate` will authenticate based upon your `User` model. If you have your custom model, Make sure that you have done the relevant configuration and settings. Specially `AUTH_USER_MODEL` should be set in settings.py

Comment: Also `Register` does not inherit from either `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser` and it doesn't appear to have a custom manager as well (to implement `create_user`, etc. methods). Please refer the documentation on [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Answer (score 0):

I may be out of touch, but

1. the fields youre using are premade in the standard auth backend which you easily set to use those fields. A good tutorial for this is apart of this youtube series  https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kQkZp-j9PNyKq7Yw5VYjq9

Or check out a extended example with password reset etc in the register app of this repo https://github.com/HarryLudemann/Job-Search

2. If you still require making your own custom model i suggest you using a 'custom authbackend' this is nearly always the way togo unless you use the prebuild form check it ou here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/
3. If You still want to use the setuo youre using you should be using the built in forms, this allows you to use the cleaned_data method check out the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/
   Or look for a example in the github repo above.

If this does not answer help please post any more code, errors or info you have. Also ensure you have run the makemigrations and migrate aswell as mugrate your server setup. Hope this somewhat helps